# How to get distinct count for each table by kusto (Azure Data Exploer)

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have lots of table with different name but with the same schema in a database such like:

```
let _t1 = datatable(Guid:string, name:string)
[
'a00001','n1',
'a00001', 'n2',
'a00001', 'n1',
'a00002', 'n3',
'a00002', 'n2',
'a00003', 'n1',
];
let _t2 = datatable(Guid:string, Name:string)
[
'a00011','n2',
'a00023', 'n2',
'a00032', 'n1',
'a00045', 'n3',
'a00032', 'n7',
'a00083', 'n5',
];

...
```

I only know how to get the count distinct Guid with specified table name.

```
_t1
| summarize Count=count() by Guid;
| count;
_t2
| summarize Count=count() by Guid;
| count;
...
```

How can I get the distinct count of Guid for each table by one kusto command such like:

```
table_name| Guid_count
-------------------
t1|3
t2|6
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the `union` operator, while specifying the `withsource` option.

for example:

```
let _t1 = view() {datatable(Guid:string, name:string)
[
'a00001','n1',
'a00001', 'n2',
'a00001', 'n1',
'a00002', 'n3',
'a00002', 'n2',
'a00003', 'n1',
]}
;
let _t2 = view() { datatable(Guid:string, Name:string)
[
'a00011','n2',
'a00023', 'n2',
'a00032', 'n1',
'a00045', 'n3',
'a00032', 'n7',
'a00083', 'n5',
]}
;
union withsource=source _t*
| summarize dcount(Guid) by source
```

-->

```
| source | dcount_Guid |
|--------|-------------|
| _t2    | 5           |
| _t1    | 3           |
```